# Reverse String: Why is this crashing?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to implment this simple string reversal function, but it keeps crashing. I've done this a hundred times but I usually use string instead of char*. What am I missing?

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    //First determine the size of the string
    int length = 0;
    char* temp = str;
    while(*temp)
    {
      temp++;
      length++;
    }

    int start = 0;
    int end = length - 1;

    while(start < end)
    {
        char temp = str[start];
        str[start] = str[end];   // I get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS here for start = 0
        str[end] = temp;
        start++; end--;
    }

    cout<<"Reversed: "<<string(str)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you attempt to reverse a constant (literal) string? That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: You may want to use strlen(char*) instead of your length finding loop

Comment: `char str[] = "Test"; reverse(str);`

Comment: Is the string null terminated? What line does it crash on?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was trying to modify a string constant and that's why it was crashing. I will accept an answer and close once the 8 minutes have passed.

Comment: `str+sizeof(char)*length`: this is wrong.  You are lucky that `sizeof(char) == 1`, but if you had an `int *` and did `ptr + sizeof(int) * length`, you would not get what you expect.  Pointer arithmetic accounts for the size; you should not include the multiplier explicitly.

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate, but I can't delete it since it has answers. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
reverse("Test");
```

By definition, a constant cannot be modified. In the code above, "Test" is a string constant.